# how to select element that does NOT have a link inside it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

Given this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/activity_stream">Activity Stream</a></li>
  <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/likes">Likes</a></li>
  <li>Favorites</li>
  <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/follows">Follows</a></li>
  <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/sketchbook_comments">Whiteboard</a></li>

</ul>
```

I want to inject the `class="current"` into the single line item that does NOT have a link inside it.

How do I use jQuery to find an element that does NOT contain a child?

Answer (score 8):

Select `<li>` element that has no `<a>` child using the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$("li:not(:has(a))").addClass("current");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFyrX/2/)

**-- EDIT --**

While this might be the shortest solution, readability aside, it definitely is not the best one in regards to speed.

With that in mind, I would suggest you check a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674087/45254) provided by [@bazmegakapa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468793/bazmegakapa).

Since this is something you (or anyone else including me) might end up using more than once, I have expanded jQuery a bit with this plugin/method you can use in order to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code:

```
jQuery.fn.thatHasNo = function(element, method) {
  if (typeof method === "undefined" || method === null) method = "children";
  return this.not(function() {
    return $(this)[method](element).length;
  });
};
```

Which you can call with:

```
$("li").thatHasNo("a").addClass("current");
```

This extension will, by default (if second argument to method is not passed), check if there are any direct descendants ([children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)) that match provided selector. However, you can provide any [tree-traversal parameter](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) as second argument to method. So, this can be written as either of the following:

```
$("li").thatHasNo("a", "children").addClass("current");
//...
$("li").thatHasNo("a", "find").addClass("current");
//...
$("li").thatHasNo(".class", "siblings").addClass("lame");
```

I have updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFyrX/6/) to reflect that.

Comment: I have added some notes concerning these selectors (`:has()` and `:not`) into my answer.

Comment: +1 Great plugin :). May I suggest `typeof method == 'undefined'` instead of `method == null`?

Comment: You can add that, but since it is an argument and by definition already defined, there is no need to check for undefined :)

Comment: It will be `undefined` if you omit the parameter when you call the function. It works for you because you use `==`, would not work with `===` because it is not `null`.

Comment: You are right, I just realized the same :) JavaScript can be weird sometimes. Originally this was piece of coffeescript: https://gist.github.com/1540061

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method (which is basically a negated `.filter()`) with a filter function.

```
$('li') /* select the elements you want to test */
    .not(function () { /* run a filter function on them */
        /* those that have a direct children link (use find() if you need
        any kind of children) will return true thus excluded */
        return $(this).children('a').length; 
    })
    .addClass('current'); /* add our beloved class */
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zJuhg/)

---

You could also use complicated selectors, as [@Krule suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673988/468793), but I find it less readable and even the [jQuery manual on :not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) warns against it:

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable
>   selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
>   selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Also, [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is not really recommended as well:

> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").has(selector/DOMElement) instead.

Comment: I have added a note pointing to your answer and expanded a bit on it by extending jQuery with `thatHasNo` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").each(function(){
    if($(this).children().length == 0){
        //found current..
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will only work if the `li` has no child elements at all. I mean, the OP only wanted those that have no `a` child.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you just add a `<span>` element inside of your `<li>` to differentiate it between the elements that have links in them.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/activity_stream">Activity Stream</a></li>
    <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/likes">Likes</a></li>
    <li><span>Favorites</span></li>
    <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/follows">Follows</a></li>
    <li><a href="/artists/gil_elvgren/sketchbook_comments">Whiteboard</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li a { /* Link CSS */ }
ul li span { /* Current CSS */ }
```

Comment: If he could do that, why not just add the class there?

Comment: This answer does not address the problem.